# Width of C# Label before it is shown?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I need to know which width the label will have with `AutoSize = true;` **before the form is shown** so I can position other controls relatively to the label. Actually I have no access to the form only to the parent Control.

*(Working completely without Designer. That means just code.)*
*(Measure string in Graphics is unreliable so I can't use that.)*

```
Label label = new Label();
label.AutoSize = true;
label.Location = new Point(x, y);            
label.Text = "hello world";
myParent.Controls.Add(label);

// more control generation follows, THEN form is shown
```

Comment: why do you want label width?

Comment: @Nimesh To position other controls relatively to the label.

Comment: Can you use a table layout panel to manage the positions of controls? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: When do you show the form? Before or after `myParent.Controls.Add(label);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you cannot get the label width before adding it into its parent control. just place the location after Controls.Add

```
Label label = new Label();
label.AutoSize = true;
label.Text = "hello world";
myParent.Controls.Add(label);
label.Left = cntControl1.Left - label.Width;
label.Top = cntControl1.Top;
```

Comment: Oh well, easier than I thought ^^